# Keystrokes in right top corner

Tags: macos

A friend of mine has a setting turned on on his macbook. As you can see in the screenshot below, the shift, function, control, alt and command keys show up in the top right corner when pressed. Where can this setting be turned off?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It must be something like :

> System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard > Sticky keys options > Display pressed keys on screen

Comment: You can mark the question as answered of the left :)